# How can I install tcl/tk8.6 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

How can I install tcl/tk8.6 on Ubuntu 12.04?

The default repositories for Ubuntu 12.04 include tcl/tk8.5 which I have installed but I need the latest version. Is there a PPA that I could add which includes tcl/tk8.6 or is there another way?

Note: As far as I can tell the latest version of Ubuntu has 8.6 as default.

Comment: I'm confused, you accepted the A where you have to compile from source, rather than install a prebuilt .deb file from a repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there are Ubuntu packages available, but if not, you could build from source and install to `/usr/local`.  This means you'll end up with 8.5 (from the distro) and 8.6 installed.  To favour 8.6 by default, make sure `/usr/local` is in your ld.so.cache; I think ubuntu does this by default.  To check:

```
grep "/usr/local/lib" /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
```

If you get nothing, create an `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf` with one line, `/usr/local/lib`.  In either case, run `ldconfig` (presuming you've already built and installed tcl/tk).

Add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` to your default environment.  This will make the linker prefer those libraries to the distro ones, which is fine unless you have previously done wonky things in /usr/local.  You'll also need `/usr/local/bin` *before* `/usr/bin` in $PATH, if it is not that way already.

You should now default to using 8.6.  Leaving 8.5 installed is just a lazy way of ensuring the package manager has it for dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 versions of [TCL/Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/8.6.html) that you can install on your system, beyond building it yourself from source.

#### Active State

You can use Active States binary distributions of their Community Editions of TCL/Tk. They offer 8.6.1.0 [32-bit](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads/thank-you?dl=http://downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTcl/releases/8.6.1.0/ActiveTcl8.6.1.0.297577-linux-ix86-threaded.tar.gz) & [64-bit](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads/thank-you?dl=http://downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTcl/releases/8.6.1.0/ActiveTcl8.6.1.0.297577-linux-x86_64-threaded.tar.gz) from their [download page](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads).

#### DEB files

The other method(s) are covered on the TCL/Tk's project page, titled: [Binary Distributions](http://wiki.tcl.tk/668). I would probably go with [tombert's tcltk](https://bitbucket.org/tombert/tcltk/downloads). They maintain all the 32-bit and 64-bit versions as `.deb` files there, and the packages are built on LTS Ubuntu (12.04) which is what you're looking for.

[image: ss of d/ls]